# json not working in code

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have some code how to link php using  json.

```js
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'ganesh', '5565','ganesh');
$sql = "INSERT INTO `equation`VALUES('','123','123')";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

 echo ' Updated successfully';

?>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("insert12.php", function(result){
            $.each(result, function(result){
                $("#file").html(result);
            });
        });
    });
});
  
</script>

<input type="text" id="input"placeholder="Search..." >
<button>solve</button>

<div id="result">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
<ul id="file">
  
  
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

json are not working how to get the input data please help me. for example input(some text) output(some text) are print using json

Comment: what code is there in insert12.php

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do - if your input is just "some text" then why do you need JSON? You haven't shown the format of the output. The only PHP that you've shown does not return JSON. (Also, it doesn't make sense to set `$("#file").html(result)` inside a loop - every iteration will just update the same element.)

Comment: use json_encode() for encoding JSON in PHP.

Comment: there is a php code its placed in top of my question.

Comment: i get the data from php (update successfully) via json. but not get any data in the #file id .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your PHP code you have to give response in JSON format

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'ganesh', '5565','ganesh');
$sql = "INSERT INTO `equation`VALUES('','123','123')";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$response=array("type"=>"success","message"=>"Updated successfully");
ob_clean();
echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

try encode your result to cast the array into JSON format using `json_encode($response)` as @Haresh mentioned and add `header('Content-Type: application/json');` avoid using `echo`

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'ganesh', '5565','ganesh');
$sql = "INSERT INTO `equation`VALUES('','123','123')";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

json_encode(array("type"=>"success","message"=>"Updated successfully"));

?>
```